# View State for Custom DropDownList control

Tags: asp.net, controls, drop-down-menu, viewstate

I'm having an issue maintaining a selected value on a custom DropDownList control.  I figured if the viewstate property was enabled on the base control, everything would be all set, i've found that isn't the case.  I think another question I have is maybe I should just be using the Request object to get/set the values?  My control is as follows.

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:TicketStatusDropdownControl runat=server></{0}:TicketStatusDropdownControl>")]
public class TicketStatusDropdownControl : DropDownList
{

    private string _defaultValue = string.Empty;
    private string _selectedItem = string.Empty;
    private string _selectedValue = string.Empty;

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (_defaultValue != string.Empty)
        {
            this.Items.Add(new ListItem(_defaultValue));
        }

        foreach (string item in TicketWorkflowStates.getWorkflowStates())
        {
            this.Items.Add(new ListItem(item));
        }

        base.Render(writer);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the LoadViewState() and SaveViewState() methods - set and retrieve ViewState values there?

Comment: Fairly new to the viewstate thing and creating custom controls, what i've come up with so far is.        protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
        {
            if (savedState != null)
            {
                object selectValue = (object)savedState;
                base.LoadViewState(savedState);
            }
        }

        protected override object SaveViewState()
        {
            object selectValue = new object();
            selectValue = base.SelectedValue;

            return selectValue;
        }

Comment: Didn't even need it, I was able to use the ControlState provided by the control.. I was adding my list items in the Render Method instead of OnPreRender, which apparently kills the Control/ViewState of that data.